# Java Immutable Builder classes not detected by IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I keep on wondering why IntelliJ cannot detect the classes which are auto-generated by [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/):

[image]

The code for the `RemoteEntityACL` is this:

```
@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(visibility = Value.Style.ImplementationVisibility.PRIVATE)
public interface RemoteEntityACL extends Serializable {
  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default List<String> read() {
    return new LinkedList<>();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default List<String> write() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default Boolean publicRead() {
    return false;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default Boolean publicWrite() {
    return false;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Value.Default
  default List<RemotePropertyACL> propertyACLs() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: The immutable classes generated by the annotation processor don't exist until you compile the annotated classes. Does the problem go away after you rebuild the project from the `Build > Rebuild Project` menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to latest version should help fix this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
   <artifactId>value</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There appears to be a bug in how certain fields get generated in version 2.5. In my case, the Builder pattern did not generate the builder at all when I renamed a class; even when I rebuilt the entire project. The only fix was upgrading to 2.8.